# How can I add data from multiple rows in MySQL into one row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My table recreated in Excel:

[image]

I have a table that im pulling from a mySQL database that looks like this. Each person has a unique ID for themselves and they are staying in rooms with unique IDs. Currently my query returns on a by person basis, I would like so that 1 row = 1 room, with the members of the room getting added in their own columns with Guest1_First, Guest1_Last, Guest1_dob, Guest2_First, Guest2_Last etc...

I have tried doing this with concats and group by, but there always seems to be an error along the lines of "Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'gm.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Also there is not a consistent amount of people in rooms, but there is a maximum of 6. How can I model my query so that 1 row = 1 room?

[Expected result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfAv9.png)

Comment: You'll need to know the maximum number of guests in advance to perform a standard "pivot". If that is not known you'll need to use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I think you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @TheImpaler there can be max 6 per room, if you mean maximum number of guests in total it could be up to 2500, but we don't have a definitive answer for that as it changes as people book/cancel. I have never used dynamix sql

Comment: @basha04 i added an expected results example to the post

Answer (score 0):

this will give you list of all guests associated with one room id in one row

```
select 
room_id,
group_concat(guest1,guest2.....n) as  list_of_all_guests
from [table name]
group by 1
```